# Recommended way to start with Javascript for client- and server-side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm thinking about to switch in middle term to node.js for server-side and mostly jQuery and scriptaculous for client-side web development.
For the scripting I'm planning to use coffeescript.

- do you think it's okay to use coffeescript or should I learn "plain" Javascript?
- What resources e.g. books, e-books, mailinglist, papers etc. would you recommend?

Comment: [Smooth CoffeeScript](http://autotelicum.github.com/Smooth-CoffeeScript/) is a _must_ if you want to skip learning javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just picked up Node.js about 2 weeks ago.  For reference here is the "stack" I am using:
-[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)
-[Expressjs](http://expressjs.com/)
-[Jade Template Engine](http://jade-lang.com/)
-[Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) as my wrapper for [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) (a "NoSQL" database)

I have been loving it so far and I came in with only a basic working knowledge of Javascript with a little jQuery experience.
I have to say right off the bat, don't use CoffeeScript.  I tried it and a friend of mine who started Node.js at the same time tried it.  While it is very interesting, it is still buggy and the code it produces isn't a great style (in my opinion).  The biggest reason not to use it, is that Javascript is a "C" syntax styled language and if you can learn the general syntax of these kinds of languages, you will be doing yourself a HUGE favor and you will find your abilities better able to translate to C, C++, Objective-C, C#, PHP and others.

Good luck with learning!  It's a great choice from my opinion.

Comment: I think your reason for using javascript over coffeescript is rather poor. The code coffeescript outputs is generally good. Remember js is functional & prototypical OO. Using it as a clasical OO or a procudural language is limiting yourself.

Comment: @Raynos : I said that was simply my opinion of the code that Coffeescript produces.  My "biggest reason" for not choosing it (as I said in my answer) is that you are not going to help your career or your general knowledge of c-style syntaxes by avoiding them.  That is what Coffeescript is, a way to avoid writing c-style syntax.

Answer (score 2):

[JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596517742)

Useful regardless which frameworks you are using.  Everyone using JavaScript should give this a read.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations and good luck on your switching to technology frameworks that is hot!

> Use of coffeescript is a good choice. But learning our plain old
>   JavaScript is a must and will come handy at the time of debugging.
>   Another reasoning could be that after all, coffeescript is only meant
>   to generate JavaScript, at any point in time during development, for
>   whatever reason, you can/may always chuck it out thinking of using
>   generated Javascript files with the intention of continuing UI
>   development with just Javascript and at such a point in time what will
>   save you is your knowledge of Javascript.
>   Yet another reason for learning Javascript would be that it is the bottom-line or common
>   denominator for both the frameworks - node.js and coffeescript.
>   Learning it should help you appreciate the use of those frameworks and
>   also in tweaking something or other

- Resources to learn what - both node.js and coffeescript? Please find some of them below:
- [How do I get started with NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-nodejs/5511507#5511507) This question was posted on StackOverflow and has pointers to cool resources. Click.Read.Click.
- [CoffeeScript Cookbook](http://coffeescriptcookbook.com/)
- [RailsCast on CofeeScript Basics](http://railscasts.com/episodes/267-coffeescript-basics)
- [CoffeeScript Basics – A Teach Me To Code Tutorial](http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/coffeescript-basics-a-teach-me-to-code-tutorial/)
- [CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/book/tbcoffee/coffeescript) should be yet another page turner from The Pragmatic Bookshelf
- [Clientside CoffeeScript with jQuery — Victus Spiritus](http://www.victusspiritus.com/2011/05/30/clientside-coffeescript-with-jquery/)
- [Rocking Out With CoffeeScript](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/rocking-out-with-coffeescript/)

Answer (score 1):

The YUI theater has some great videos on the good parts of javascript and they have a lot of node js videos.  I first started coding js and ExtJS(3.*) the framework helped me learn a lot about js.  The Ext.extend method helps learn the good parts of prototypes and functions.  Once you start using then understanding the source code the sky is the limit.

edit-

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/